# If the chances of having a car crash in the next year is 12%, is the chance of having a car crash in the next month 1%?

Tags: probability

This is about dividing probabilities.  I have a foggy memory from my school days that this is a bad thing to do, but I can't remember why.

So, if the chances of having a car crash in the next year is 12%, is the chance of having a car crash in the next month 1%?

Can annual statistics be divided by 12 to get monthly statistics?

Comment: In general, no.  I strongly doubt that it is true in real life, for example, as I expect crashes are quite seasonal.

Comment: [here](https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/seasonal-trends-us-car-accidents) is some real world data, supporting my suspicion that car crashes (like most social phenomena) are seasonal.

Comment: Even assuming the probability of crashing any given month is the same (which is a stretch not just because of seasonal variations but also because some months have more days in them, which means more oppurtunity to crash), you have to be more specific. Is $12\%$ the probability of being in _exactly one_ crash, or _at least_ one crash? Do you stop driving after a crash, or keep driving as before?

Comment: Worth noting:  if you assumed that there was a $1\%$ chance of a crash each month then there would be an $1-.99^{12}\approx .114$ probability of a crash over the year (assuming, perhaps unphysically, that having crashes in two different months were independent events).  To get $.12$ on the year you need a monthly rate of  about $.0106$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The probabilty per month is:

$$ (1-p)^{12} = 1-0.12 $$
$$ p = 1 - \sqrt[12]{0,88} = 0,01059624... $$